# how can we tell the host that we are requesting a webpage from android device

Tags: android

Actually I'm using HttpClient() and HttpPost() methods for downloading the html source 
here is the code for downloading:

```
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(_url);
try {
  // Execute HTTP Post Request
  HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
  responseBody = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
    }
```

If I execute the above code some sites like www.google.com (which will give user agent specific code (HTML code)), not giving whole information suitable for android. So I can tell the host that I'm requesting webpage from android device.

Comment: what is the purpose of this task? do you wish to display the webpage in your application?

Comment: ya.. but in my application I'll store the webpage and display it in offline..